# Not getting the response

Tags: php, android

i am creating a application in which i send some parameters to my web service right now it is running on local host and it gives me json response. Somehow it is not working after this line **HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);**. Can anyone help please.
ps. my webservice is working absolutely fine

test_class.java

```
package com.vitarkasolutions.tracker;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class test_class extends Activity{
    final static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/tracker/index.php" ;
    String xyz ="";
    String tag ="login";    
    String name="varun";
    String email="varun@gmail.com";
    int lat= 10;
    int lang = 20;
    int phone_no= 10;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
     Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);   
     btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            registerUser(name, email, tag, phone_no, lat, lang);    
        }
    });

    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void registerUser(String name, String email,String register_tag, int phone_no ,int lat , int lang )
{

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone_no",String.valueOf(phone_no)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",String.valueOf(lat) ));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", String.valueOf(lang)));

            try {
            parsing data = new parsing();
            data.execute(params);
                //AsyncTask parsing =new parsing().execute(params);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


public  class parsing extends AsyncTask<List<? extends NameValuePair>, Void, Void> {    
    // Making HTTP request

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<? extends NameValuePair>... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.e("tag", "parse function called");            
        try{
                // defaultHttpClient
         DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        Log.d("tag", "post");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params[0]));    
        Log.d("tag", "entity");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);                   
        Log.d("tag", "response");
        final int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
                { 
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
                    Log.d("not Connected", "connected");
                }else{
                    Log.d("Connected", "connected");
                }
                Log.d("Con", "connected");
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();                                               
               InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();       
               Reader Reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
                 Log.e("tag2", is.toString());         
                 Gson gson = new Gson();                             
                 user user = gson.fromJson(Reader,user.class);   
                 Log.e("tag3", "done");
                 Log.e("tag4", user.toString());
                 Log.e("tag4", user.name);
                 Log.d("tag4", user.email);

        } 
        catch  (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

}       
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  Are you getting any error or seeing some crashes?

Comment: No actually i am not getting any response. SO i am using log() to check that after which line my code is not running and Log() after http response is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code as a sample for webservice and download the jersey jar and add it to your lib
```

Download using:

https://jersey.java.net/download.html

Add jar file using following procedure :-

Right click on the project--->Build Path--->Configure Build Path...--->In left side you have to choose Java Build Path--->Libraries--->Add External JARs--->ok--->ok

Hope this will resolve the issue

```
  package com.example.login;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
  import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
  import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
  import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
  import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
  import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
  import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.AlertDialog;
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.DialogInterface;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import com.example.login.ConnectionDetector;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
public EditText uname,pwd;
ImageView btnlog1;
public Button btncancel1;
public String db_select;
 String mUname;
 String mPwd;
String temp;
Intent intObj;
Intent intent = null;

  Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
ConnectionDetector cd;

private String SERVICE_URL = "http://100.2.1.97:8080/Database/path";
//private String SERVICE_URL = "http://10.1.1.138:8080/Database/path";
private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btnlog1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.login);
    //btncancel1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //SERVICE_URL=ServerURL.URL+"/msd";

    btnlog1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            mUname=uname.getText().toString();
            mPwd=pwd.getText().toString();
 //                 display("Login clicked");
            if(!mUname.equalsIgnoreCase("") &&   

   !mPwd.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                cd = new    
     ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  
   isInternetPresent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(isInternetPresent)
                {


                try
                {
                    validat_user(mUname,mPwd);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    display("Network error.\nPlease check with   
   your network settings.");
                    uname.setText("");
                    pwd.setText("");
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    display("No Internet Connection...");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                display("Please enter the data in all Required 
    fields...");
            }
        }
    });

}
public void display(String msg) 
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


private void validat_user(String stg1, String stg2)
{
    db_select=stg1;
    WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, this, "Login   
     in progress...");

    wst.addNameValuePair("EMP_ID", stg1);
    wst.addNameValuePair("EMP_PWD", stg2);

    wst.execute(new String[] { SERVICE_URL });

}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void no_net()
{
    display( "No Network Connection");
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new  
    AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
    alertDialog.setMessage("You don't have internet connection.\nElse please 
    check the Internet Connection Settings.");
    //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error_info);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {   
            alertDialog.cancel();
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton2("Use Local DataBase", new 
     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            display( "Accessing local DataBase.....");
            alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

  private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    public static final int POST_TASK = 1;

    private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

    // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
    private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT =3000;

    // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
    private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

    private int taskType = POST_TASK;
    private Context mContext = null;
    private String processMessage = "Processing...";

    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

    public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage) {

        this.taskType = taskType;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.processMessage = processMessage;
    }

    public void addNameValuePair(String name, String value) {

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void showProgressDialog() {

        pDlg = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        pDlg.setMessage(processMessage);
        pDlg.setProgressDrawable(mContext.getWallpaper());
        pDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDlg.setCancelable(false);
        pDlg.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        showProgressDialog();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String url = urls[0].toString();
        String result = "";
        HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);
        if (response == null) {
            return result;
        } else {

            try {

                result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }

        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

        handleResponse(response);
        pDlg.dismiss();

    }

    // Establish connection and socket (data retrieval) timeouts
    private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

        HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

        return htpp;
    }

    private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

        // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
        // DefaultHttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            switch (taskType) {

            case POST_TASK:

                HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost(url);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                break;
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        //  display("Remote DataBase can not be connected.\nPlease check network 
    connection.");

            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return null;

        }

        return response;
    }

    private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            // Read response until the end
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }

        // Return full string
        return total.toString();
    }

  }
   public void handleResponse(String response) 

  {    
//display("Response:"+response);
    if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        JSONObject jso;
        try {
            jso = new JSONObject(response);


                String status = jso.getString("status");
          //     display("Welcome : "+UName);
                if( status.equalsIgnoreCase("") || status==null ||  
   status.equalsIgnoreCase("Failed"))
                {
                    reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    //display(status);
                    intObj=new 
    Intent(MainActivity.this,pdf.class);
                    startActivity(intObj);
                    MainActivity.this.finish();     
                }


            }
        catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, e1.getLocalizedMessage(), e1);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }


    }
    else
    {
        display("Could not able to reach Server!");
    }


    }
   public void reset()
    {
    display("Entered User ID / Password is incorrect.\nPlease enter valid User ID & 
    Password.");

    pwd.setText("");
    uname.setText("");
   }

   }
```